# Using composite key as a foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-primary-key

My Tables

Fee Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fee` (
`feeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`feeName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`feeDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`feeAmount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`universityName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`feeNumber`,`feeName`,`feeAmount`)
```

Housing Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `housing` (
`housingOfficeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`housingOfficeName` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`housingOfficeType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`housingOfficePhone` decimal(18,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`housingOfficeRoomDeposit` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`studentStatusName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`housingFeeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
`housingFeeName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`housingFee` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`hOffTrm` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`universityName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I'm trying to do is reference the feeAmount,feeNumber, and feeName from the fee table and add it to the housingfee, housingfeeName, and housingFeenumber columns in the housing table. Since the feeAmount and feeName columns are not unique I decided to make a composite key out of feeNumber, feeName, and feeAmount. The only part of the composite key I really need referenced is feeAmount. feeName and feeNumber are not really important. using phpmyadmin.

Comment: From the schema you have shown it is onclear how to relate the fee records top the housing records.  HOw do you know which fees are applicable to which housing records in order top determine which fee amounts should be added together?

Comment: there are a total of 5 fees in the fee table that are applicable to the housing record. I named those fees something along the lines of "Housing: Winward Commons" or "Housing: Apartment Terrace" thats who I know that they are applicable.

Comment: That's fine and dandy, but you have not explained how your SCHEMA expresses the relationship.  If you are trying to join these two tables, what fields are common?

Comment: `housingFeeNumber `housingFeeName 'housingFee are the same as feeNumber, feeName, and feeAmount.

Comment: Oh that is ugly why would there simply be a single FeeID field and you look up the Fee table to get the name and amount columns?  Why duplicate that data in two places?  Is there some performance reason for this denormalization?

Comment: Also `INT(255)` column definition makes no sense for a column whose maximum (SIGNED) value is 4294967295 (ten characters plus one possible character for `-`). Unless you are just planning on zero-filling the column to 255 characters for display for some reason you should not be using 255 here.

Comment: You might be right. The housing table might be redundant. I may have over thought that table. I think I will just keep the fees in the fees table and not try to reference them in the housing table. I just wanted the housing table to have all the necessary information about housing without having to go to another table.

Comment: You would need to reference the fees in the housing tables somehow, or introduce a third tables that relates housing to fees, which would be appropriate if there were a many-to-many relationship between fees and housing records.

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no.  In general, I think it is best to avoid compound primary keys.  In this case, in particular, you do not want the fee amount or name to be part of the key.  In order to access the row, you need to know the amount.  That seems very difficult to implement.

I am guessing that an *auto incremented* primary key will work just fine.  You can then add a separate unique constraint on other columns.  So:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fee` (
    `feeNumber` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    `feeName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `feeDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `feeAmount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `universityName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     unique (feeName)
);
```

Then, another table would have `feeNumber` with an appropriate foreign key reference.  Through the reference, you can get other information -- such as the name and amount -- using a `join`.

Comment: Alright I've put auto incremented feeNumber as the primary key. But how would I get feeAmount from the fee table to the housingFeeAmount in the housing table using    join?